# How can I abort a telnet connection attempt?

Tags: windows, telnet

Suppose I execute the following in command prompt:

> telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 80

half a second later, I realize it would never connect (for whatever reason). I want to abort the connection *attempt* instead of waiting for it to timeout.

Pressing either `Ctrl + c`, `Ctrl + ]`, `Ctrl + q` or `quit` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's connecting (or failing to connect...), then there is no way to interrupt the process until it times out or close the command prompt and open again.